How can I run TesseractOCR with multiple languages one time?
Tesseract recognizes "dBμV" as "dBuV".
How can I run TesseractOCR with multiple languages one time?
Engine engine = new Engine(@".\tessdata", "eng+script/Greek", EngineMode.Default);

If there is a "u" in the blacklist, it is recognized as "ἀβμΥ".
